# Share User data between different action in the same controller in MVC

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, authentication

I want to store globally the object User (that is the table USER in my db) in my HomeController, in that way i don't have to instantiate it in every single action.
I found the following solution that works pretty fine

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
 private DatabaseContext db = new DatabaseContext();

 private User currentUser;
 private User CurrentUser 
 { 
  get 
  { 
   if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
   //This function returns the object "User" (table USER in db) based on the PK of the table
   currentUser = CustomDbFunctions.GetUserEntityFromUsername(User.Identity.Name, db);
   return currentUser;
  }
 }

 public ActionResult Index()
 {
  if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
   return View(CurrentUser);
  else
   return Redirect("login");
 }
}
```

I'd like to know if there's a better (or more elegant) way to achieve the same goal.
Please note that i'm not using the MembershipProvider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example the user object **is** instantiated in every single action (in contrast to what you said). This is because actions are usually invoked per http request and controller instances are disposed after each use.

Your code shares the instance structurally (you don't have to repeat the code) which is ok but what about sharing the code between different controllers? I'd suggest to refactor your `GetUserEntityFromUsername` a little bit so that you retrieve the object only once per request, using the `Items` container to get the request scope:

```
 public class CustomDbFunctions
 {
    const string itemsUserKey = "_itemsUserKey";
    public static User GetUserEntityFromUsername( IPrincipal principal, DatabaseContext db )
    {
        if ( principal == null || principal.Identity == null ||
             !principal.Identity.IsAuthenticated
            ) 
           return null;

        if ( HttpContext.Current.Items[itemsUserKey] == null )
        {
          // retrieve the data from the Db
          var user = db.Users.FirstOrDefault( u => u.Name == User.Identity.Name );   
          HttpContext.Current.Items[itemsUserKey] = user;
        }

        return (User)HttpContext.Current.Items[itemsUserKey];
    }
```

This way your wrapper takes care of retrieving the instance from the database once per request.

Note that this requires sharing your database context as entities should not be reused on different contexts. Fortunately, this can be done in a similar way:

```
 public class CustomDbFunctions
 {
    const string dbUserKey = "dbUserKey";
    public static DatabaseContext CurrentDatabaseContext
    {
        get
        {
            if ( HttpContext.Current.Items[dbUserKey] == null )
            { 
                DatabaseContext ctx = new DatabaseContext(); // or any other way to create instance
                HttpContext.Current.Items[dbUserKey] = ctx;
            }

            return (DatabaseContext)HttpContext.Current.Items[dbUserKey];

         }
     }
```

This way, the context instance, shared per request, is always available as

```
     CustomDbFunctions.CurrentDatabaseContext
```

Comment: I think i understood (sorry, i'm brand new to MVC and OOP).
So now i use into my Index Action the following
return View(CustomDbFunctions.GetUserEntityFromUsername(User, db))

The only question is: everytime i refresh the Index page, the code is ALWAYS checking the credential of the user (using your custom function), i'm i correct that once the User object is created (based on the credential) is not necessary everytime to retrieve the data from the db?

I'm saying this because everytime i execute your custom function the HttpContext.Current.Items[itemsUserKey] is ALWAYS null

Comment: `HttpContext.Current.Items` is initially null upon every **new request**. This is normal. However, if your single request requires complex processing, consecutive hits to the property will get cached result. I believe your slight confusion comes from the fact that you don't quite yet "feel" what is a request scope and how processing at the server starts all over again from scratch everytime you request data from the client-side (browser).